# Getting a 'list index out of range' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, error-handling

The goal of this code is to find the number of 'sh', 'th', 'wh', and 'ch' digraphs there are in any given sentence. The function keeps returning a 'list index out of range' error, when it seems like everything should be running properly.

```
exsentence = input("Enter a sentence to scan: ")
slist = list(exsentence.lower())
ch = 0
sh = 0
th = 0
wh = 0
i = 0
'''muppets = slist[i] + slist[i+1]'''
while i < len(slist):
    if slist[i] + slist[i+1] == "sh":
        sh += 1
    elif slist[i] + slist[i+1] == "ch":
        ch += 1
    elif slist[i] + slist[i+1] == "th":
        th += 1
    else:
        if slist[i] + slist[i+1] == "wh":
            wh += 1
    i+=1
print("Has {} 'ch' {} 'sh' {} 'th' {} 'wh'".format(ch,sh,th,wh))
```

Any help is very appriceciated. Thank you.

Comment: Ignore the dotsting heh I was experimenting to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i+1` will be out of `slist` bounds. You need to iterate until `slist` size - 1

```
while i < len(slist) - 1:
```

As a side note, `for` seems to be more appropriate here. Remove `i = 0` and `i+=1`

```
for i in range(len(slist) - 1):
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop with range instead:

```
exsentence = input("Enter a sentence to scan: ")
slist = list(exsentence.lower())
ch = 0
sh = 0
th = 0
wh = 0
i = 0
'''muppets = slist[i] + slist[i+1]'''
for i in range(1,len(slist)):
    if slist[i-1] + slist[i] == "sh":
        sh += 1
    elif slist[i-1] + slist[i] == "ch":
        ch += 1
    elif slist[i-1] + slist[i] == "th":
        th += 1
    elif slist[i-1] + slist[i] == "wh":
        wh += 1

print(f"Has {ch} 'ch' {sh} 'sh' {th} 'th' {wh} 'wh'")
```

start the range at 1 and check i-1 against i this way you wont go out of index range

Answer (score 0):

You are checking one position ahead of the current one. Thus you are getting the error of being out of range.

Basically, you are iterating over each position of the array, but you are checking for the nth position against the nth + 1 position. What does happen when you reach the last position? You check it with the next position, which is not defined (otherwise it would not be the last position), and thus get the out of range error.

My suggestion is to not perform the check on the last item against the next one, as there will not be any sequence anymore.

```
while i < len(slist) - 1:
if slist[i] + slist[i+1] == "sh":
    sh += 1
elif slist[i] + slist[i+1] == "ch":
    ch += 1
elif slist[i] + slist[i+1] == "th":
    th += 1
else:
    if slist[i] + slist[i+1] == "wh":
        wh += 1
i+=1
```